# How does the X-59 achieve low-noise supersonic flight?

Tags: supersonic, experimental-aircraft, shock-waves, noise-reduction, lockheed-martin-x-59-quesst

By what mechanism or combination of mechanisms does the X-59 reduce the noise produced by its sonic boom?  What are the design choices that led to this outcome? I really want to understand the issue from an aerodynamic perspective as well as a design perspective.

[image: Artist's rendering of future X-59 aircraft]
Source: [nasa.gov](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-selects-contractor-for-quiet-supersonic-flight-community-testing)

Comment: it would be helpful to have a picture in the question so we can see the details of what you are talking about.

Comment: This plane does not exist (yet).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of the date of this answer, the X-59 has not yet flown, but according to the designers...

> The ground noise is expected to be around 60 dB(A), about 1/1000 as
> loud as current supersonic aircraft. This is achieved by using a long,
> narrow airframe and canards to keep the shock waves from coalescing.
> It should create a 75 Perceived Level decibel (PLdB) thump on ground,
> as loud as closing a car door, compared with 105-110 PLdB for the
> Concorde. The central engine has a top-mounted intake for low boom,
> but inlet flow distortion due to vortices is a concern.

[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_X-59_QueSST#Design)

Additional information on this NASA project is available [here](https://www.nasa.gov/subject/7566/supersonic-flight/).